# Is there a difference in a django website deployed to aws elastic beanstalk between a mobile device or desktop computer?

Tags: python, css, django, mobile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my web app (which right now is just some templates with js and css) to aws elastic beanstalk and the website is up and running.

I used a predefined theme for the layout of the website that includes responsive design.

On a dekstop computer the website is looking fine, even if I manually resize the window. In every resolution it looks great! Every icon and image gets loaded perfectly.

Now if I want to look at the website on my smartphone (mobile device) it starts "srewing" up. It adds a white bar below the start page and on different browsers it just mixes some divs completely up, rendering them on the top of the page instead of the bottom.
Some icons also are not correctly displayed.

I tried different browsers for the desktop pc, everything fine. On the smartphone I have problems on all browsers.

I checked the website (www.meyn-computer-lotse.de) on the http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/ and there the website is also displayed perfectly.

I just cannot find my mistake...

Now I kinda have two questions:
1. Is there an easy way on a mobile device to lookup the css rules for the website, cause on the desktop pc I can easily lookup the applied rules.
2. Do I have to specify something in django or aws elastic-beanstalk for a mobile device?

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Based on your question, I think the tags should be different. You are asking about checking CSS for mobile

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to look up the CSS rules applied while using your phone, you can press F12 in your browser. If you use the Chrome browser you can toggle the device toolbar and choose between different devices you want to view your website on.

[image]

To answer your second question, to make sure the pages are responsive you can use something like Bootstrap "https://getbootstrap.com". Bootstrap takes care of the Javascript and CSS to make sure everything is displayed correctly, though sometimes you might have to choose a different layout because bootstrap has some limitations.

You can make a distinction between desktop or mobile phone users to serve them a different template which is optimized for the device they use. Here you have a few different options:

- Use [django-mobile](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile),

  > django-mobile provides a simple way to detect    mobile browsers and
  >   gives you tools at your hand to render some    different templates to
  >   deliver a mobile version of your site to the    user.
- Use [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/),

  > MobileESP has a simple API for detecting mobile devices. The API
  >   returns the simple Boolean result of TRUE if the device is the
  >   specified type, or FALSE if it isn't. For example, want to know if
  >   your visitor is on an iPhone, Android or Windows Phone device? Simply
  >   use the method DetectTierIphone().

I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you very much!

I looked at the website in Google Chrome via the F12 button and there it always looks good on IPhone X or Galaxy S5.

But then again it doesn't look good/same on my real mobile device..and that's what I don't get.

Like I said I bought the website theme, which should be responsive and I have different css for different widths and all. 
I don't really want to go through that all myself, that's why I used a preprogrammed theme.